# Rotate view and subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

I am having a problem rotating an image with subviews in an iOS 9+ app. I have a container view containing 2 subviews. The subviews are the same size as the container view. First subview contains an image from a PDF page. Second subview contains UIImageViews as subviews that sit on top of the PDF image. I use the coordinate system of the PDF to place and size the image views correctly. (Maybe I should mention that the container view is itself a subview of a UIScrollview).

The image views are properly placed and oriented whether the PDF is portrait or landscape. However, when the PDF is landscape, I would like to rotate and scale the final image so that it displays normally. One way I can do this is to rotate, transform and scale the PDF and each image view individually, putting drawing code in each view's drawRect method. This works but it's really slow.

I learned from a SO post that if I apply the rotation and transform to the CALayer of the container view, iOS applies the changes to the entire view hierarchy. This runs much more quickly when rotating a landscape image. But I have not been able to scale the final image using the layer of the container view. On an iPad I end up with a correctly rotated final image, centered horizontally at the top of the screen, but clipped on the left and right sides. The long axis of the image is still equal to the height of the screen, wider than the width of the screen.

The code in the container view is really short:

```
- (void) setOrientation:(NSInteger)orientation
{
    _orientation = orientation;
    if (orientation == foPDFLandscape)
    {
//        [[self layer] setNeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange:YES];// no effect
//        [[self layer] setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];//does not change image size or scale
//        [[self layer] setContentsScale:0.5];//does not change image size or scale

        [[self layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.9)];
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90.0 * (M_PI / 180.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        [[self layer] setTransform:transform];

//putting the scaling code here instead of before the transform makes no difference
    }
}
```

Setting the bounds, frame, or the contentsScale, either before or after the transform and in various combinations, has no effect on the final image. Nor does changing the Content Gravity Values and autoResizeMask.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to concatenate the transforms like this:

```
- (void) setOrientation:(NSInteger)orientation
{
    _orientation = orientation;
    if (orientation == foPDFLandscape)
    {
        [[self layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0)];
        CATransform3D rotate = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90.0 * (M_PI / 180.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CATransform3D scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.77, 0.77, 1.0);
        CATransform3D concat = CATransform3DConcat(rotate, scale);
        [[self layer] setTransform:concat];
    }
}
```

But this is a partial solution. The final image is clipped to the size of the screen -- OK on an iPad but not on an iPhone. Also, the image no longer responds to pinch gestures for zooming.